# Error parsing custom _id type in go mongodb project

Tags: mongodb, go, design-patterns, go-modules

I'm building a go project using mongodb as a database.

In order to make the code easily maintainable, i created a mongo provider package that is the single point of contact between my project and `mongo-driver/mongo`. That way I only use my own implementations in the rest of the project.

I wrapped the whole native driver with my own implementations. The only problem I encounter is with the `primitive.ObjectID` type.

Obviously, my structures are stored in an internal `models` package like this :

```golang
type StoredUser struct {
     Id       my_mongo_driver.Id `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
     Username string             `bson:"username"`
}
```

As you see, the `models` package does not have any contact with the native `mongo-driver/mongo` package. This is what I want.

In the `my_mongo_driver` package, I tried reimplementing the `Id` type by two different ways :

- `type Id primitive.ObjectID`
- `type Id struct {primitive.ObjectID}`

In both cases, I get an error when parsing the database results :

- First approach : `error decoding key _id: cannot decode objectID into an array`
- Second approach : `error decoding key _id: cannot decode objectID into a my_mongo_driver.Id`

How can I properly isolate my packages if my models need to use the exact native type for the parsing to work ?

Comment: Use `primitive.ObjectID` for the `Id` field, that type is the Go equivalent to MongoDB's ObjectId.

Comment: No. The idea is precisely to avoid importing the `primitive` package in the `models` package.

Comment: Then you must implement custom unmarshaling. Or don't use ObjectId in the database.